# using printers in c++

Tags: c++, printing

How do I use a printer in C++?

Comment: Printers like the physical machines? Or printing output to a screen? If the first thing, what platform?

Comment: What operating system, and what kind of printing do you want to do (text ? graphics ?) ?

Answer (score 5):

C++ itself, with its defaults libraries, does not provides direct support for printing. It depends, on a lower level, on the operating system you are using and the printing engine of your system. On a higher level, you may use a C++ library that provides an abstraction layer for printing over the operating system interface.

For instance, you may use the [Gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org) library, that provides such printing abstraction, and also provides a very good [documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/chapter-printing.html.en) full of [examples](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-printing-example.html.en#sec-printing-example-simple) on how it works.